# how to merge few columns into single column within semicolon delimiter inside of the new column in r

Tags: r, text, merge

I want to merge few columns and create a column contains list (or like dictionary in python) which are separated by semicolon.
Basically, I have this dataframe: (empty spaces are missing values)

```
ID  Event Category  Start Time  End Time    Account No.   Dosage  Doctor's_ID
1    Stroke          1/1/2011       
1   Admitted         1/6/2011               24287939                  5487
1   Diagnosed        1/25/2011      
6   Diagnosed        1/1/2011       
6   Drug       A     1/2/2011   1/10/2011                  "high"
6   Drug       B     1/7/2011   1/20/2011   35287930      "medium"
10  Drug       A    1/3/2011    1/6/2011                   "low"
10  Drug       B    1/9/2011    1/13/2011                  "high"
10  Stroke          1/8/2011
```

I want to create a column `attribute` which merge few columns in a column and within semicolon delimiter.

output file (can be text file) looks:

```
  ID    Event Category  Start Time  End Time    attributes
    1    Stroke          1/1/2011       
    1   Admitted         1/6/2011               Account No.="24287939"; Doctor's_ID="5487"
    1   Diagnosed        1/25/2011      
    6   Diagnosed        1/1/2011       
    6   Drug       A     1/2/2011   1/10/2011   Dosage="high"
    6   Drug       B     1/7/2011   1/20/2011   Account No.="35287930"; Dosage="medium"
    10  Drug       A    1/3/2011    1/6/2011    Dosage="low"
    10  Drug       B    1/9/2011    1/13/2011   Dosage="high"
    10  Stroke          1/8/2011
```

my purpose is to write a text file which the columns are separated by tab delimiter ("\t") and attribute data (the last column) which is like a list  separated by ";".

more detail about desired output provided here http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/eventflow/manual/chapter_start.html#1.4

how can I do it in R?thx

Comment: can you give the dput() of your dataframe?

Comment: below, the data is provided. thanks to @MKR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `apply` function and pass row-wise data for last 3 columns. The good part with `apply` is that row data is passed to function as a `named-vector` where `name` matches with columns names.

Now, one has to first combine `name` with `value` of named-vector using `paste` and then again merge in one string using `collapse=";"` argument of function `paste0`. The solution will be as:

```
cbind(df[1:4],Attribute = 
   apply(df[,5:7],1, function(x)paste0(paste(names(x[!is.na(x)]),x[!is.na(x)], sep = "="),
   collapse = ";")))
# ID Event.Category Start.Time  End.Time                             Attribute
# 1  1         Stroke   1/1/2011      <NA>
# 2  1       Admitted   1/6/2011      <NA> Account.No.=24287939;Doctor.s_ID=5487
# 3  1      Diagnosed  1/25/2011      <NA>
# 4  6      Diagnosed   1/1/2011      <NA>
# 5  6   Drug       A   1/2/2011 1/10/2011                           Dosage=high
# 6  6   Drug       B   1/7/2011 1/20/2011    Account.No.=35287930;Dosage=medium
# 7 10   Drug       A   1/3/2011  1/6/2011                            Dosage=low
# 8 10   Drug       B   1/9/2011 1/13/2011                           Dosage=high
# 9 10         Stroke   1/8/2011      <NA>
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text =
'ID  "Event Category"  "Start Time"  "End Time"    "Account No."   Dosage  Doctor\'s_ID
1   Stroke          1/1/2011         NA          NA                NA       NA      
1   Admitted         1/6/2011        NA       24287939      NA            5487
1   Diagnosed        1/25/2011      NA          NA                NA       NA
6   Diagnosed        1/1/2011       NA          NA                NA       NA
6   "Drug       A"     1/2/2011   1/10/2011       NA           "high"         NA
6   "Drug       B"     1/7/2011   1/20/2011   35287930      "medium"         NA
10  "Drug       A"    1/3/2011    1/6/2011          NA         "low"         NA
10  "Drug       B"    1/9/2011    1/13/2011         NA         "high"         NA
10  Stroke          1/8/2011        NA          NA                NA       NA',
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks, I also like to have some conditions like if(category=="B") then pick up Dosage column for attribute column. how can I do it?

Comment: @Cina I think a simple `ifelse` will be able to help you. But it would be better if you can modify your question and show expected output then I can incorporate it in my answer easily.